# Gremlin Customized Output using project

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

[image]

[gremlinify: https://gremlify.com/l3gujyc2e5](https://gremlify.com/l3gujyc2e5)
pls execute Query 2 and 2.1 to see the difference.

I have an acyclic uni-directional graph in Cosmos Graph Db.

My graph has 2 types of vertices:

- **item**(Label: ItemDefinition, itemName: ix)
- **processor**(Label: ProcessorDefinition, processorName: px)

Every processor takes 1 or more items and produces 1 or more items.

**Problem Statement:**
given some itemsList, disabledProcessorsList, traverse the graph starting from items in the itemsList until the path is exhausted or when we reach any processor in the disabledProcessorsList.

**Eg**:

itemsList : 'i6'

disabledProcessorsList: 'p12','p13','p14'

**Query**:

```
g.V().has('ItemDefinition','ItemName', within('i26'))
.until(__.outE().count().is(0))
.repeat(out().hasLabel('ProcessorDefinition')
.not(or( has('ProcessorName', within('p12','p13','p14'))))
.store('ProcessorsInPath').out())
.select('ProcessorsInPath').unfold().dedup()
.project('Processor', 'InputItems', 'OutputItems')
.by(__.valueMap('ProcessorName').select('ProcessorName'))
.by(__.in().values('ItemName').order().fold())
.by(__.out().values('ItemName').order().fold())
```

In the above query while traversing down i'm just collecting the vertices labelled ProcessorDefinition and listing **all** its inputs and outputs

**Expected output** for the above query:

```
[
  {
    "Processor": [
      "p11"
    ],
    "InputItems": [
      "i25",
      "i26",
      "i27",
      "i28"
    ],
    "OutputItems": [
      "i29"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Just FYI.. Even if p13 is not in disabledProcessors the expected output should be the same as p11 cannot reach p13 without traversing through p12 which is disabled**

**Actual output** for the above query:

```
[]
```

How do I write the query to get the expected output?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can edit the question to add some `addV` and `addE` steps that build the  sample graph shown in the picture, providing a tested answer will be easier. Steps commonly used to produce the type of output you are looking for include `project` and `group`.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence thanks for the input. I have updated the question with a new image and graph URL. please let me know if any further information is needed.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cap() instead of store() fixed my issue. Looks like it has something to do with the lazy evaluation of store().

> cap() will force an eager evaluation of all previous step, pretty similar to barrier(). Indeed you can see cap(xxx) as a shorthand for barrier().select(xxx)

source: https://www.datastax.com/blog/gremlin-recipes-7-variables-handling

https://gremlify.com/aamt3fv745